# img in vscode horizontal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a horizontal img but when I import it in Visual Studio Code then it appeard horizontal. Somehow vscode convert the vertical img to horizontal.

Can someone help me where the problem is?

[image: see img]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with many browsers to keep the original orientation of images. This happens mostly with high-resolution images with EXIF orientation.

**Workaround**: Scale down(Resize) the image or edit it in an image editor. Or save as PNG first. Save again as JPG from the PNG. Use the new JPG.

Hope this solve.